# Meteor custom oauth package

Tags: meteor, oauth

I'm need a create custom package for using oauth with external service, but have no idea how to make it. I'm tryed to clone accounts-github package into my project and modyfy it, but it not working. 
Some code here.

```
//test.html
<template name = 'test'>
    <a href="#" class=".gitLogin">Login</a>
</test>

//test.js
Template.test.events({
    'click .gitLogin': function() {
    return Meteor.loginWithGithub();
}
});
```

Error here:

```
Meteor.loginWithGithub is not a function
```

My steps for installing accounts-github package:

```
—clone from repo to app/packages directory
—modifyed name of package in package.js file
—meteor add my:package
—Donewithout any errors
```

But as you can see it not working.

Main question: how to create or modify existing package to use another oauth provider?

Provider is wargaming.net is not providing secret code like a facebook or google.

p.s. and i'm using windows

Comment: Have you renamed your folder to `my-package` as well?

Answer (score 1):

There are two packages for each oauth service. The other one has all of the logic related to the service. Check out the `github` package https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/github